# Algorithmic Trading: Normalization and Selection of Technical Indicators for Artificial Neural Networks

Tags: equities, trading, algorithmic-trading, machine-learning, neural-networks

I study on algorithmic trading for a while based on technical indicators. I started to learn about neural networks and want to use technical trading indicators in this approach.

However, I am not sure how to normalize, read past questions, but there is no clear answer.

Is there anybody who can suggest a starting point?

Comment: Even accounting for the upvotes to this question, I actually think it is either unclear or too broad. All that is really mentioned is "technical indicators", "normalize" and "neural networks". Since each of these terms contains a considerably wide scope I can't answer this, and that is also why I suspect you have found "no clear answer". I would suggest you reformulate this with more of a narrower focus on precisely what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5):

This question is broad, and the normalisation strategy is going to depend on the nature of your indicator.

Assuming the technical indicators are a time series, then two simple approaches for normalising your data are:

1. Calculate the difference between each time step. If you are feeding multiple signals into a neural network you should confirm the values are of similar magnitude, and scale if necessary (obviously your features will not be neatly bounded [0,1] unless that's the nature of the indicator). An easy to understand [Python tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_104_Finance_Timeseries_Basic_with_Pandas_Numpy.ipynb) using this strategy can be found in the Microsoft Cognitive Toolkit; or
2. Calculate the returns / percentage change of the indicator at each time step which will give you a scaled result between 0 and 1. i.e. `(t2 - t1) / t1` where `t1` is the signal at time step 1 and `t2` is the signal at time step 2.

[Machine Learning Mastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/start-here/) is a good resource for tutorials that will include appropriate normalisation steps for different sorts of features with a strong focus on time series data, and to a degree for different deep learning models.

Finally, if you are up to the challenge, review the chapter Fractionally Differentiated Features in [Advances in Financial Machine Learning](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/1119482089/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_U_gySFCbEJBQ77G) by Marcos Lopez De Prado. Excellent thinking and review of the challenges of dealing with the kinds of features you want to use.